# Adding touch effect in custom View - Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've created a custom `View` with a text inside:

```
canvas.drawText(text,
            bounds.centerX(),
            _getTextVerticalCenterPosition(bounds, paint),
            paint);
```

*`_getTextVerticalCenterPosition` just returns y-position.*

Now on touch (`onTouchEvent`) I'd like to set any effect for user to visually feel the touch but have no idea where to start. `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` should initiate the effect and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` should end it and return the text to its initial look. And what about "sliding" the finger on the screen. It'd be great if the text's initial look would be returned right after finger leaving the bounds not after the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (bounds.contains(x, y)) {
                // Text pressed

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or is it possible to use basic views, such as `Button`, in my custom one and combine them with arcs and paths?

---

**Solution**:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (bounds.contains(x, y)) {
                // Text pressed
                _setTextColor(mOnTouchColor);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            _setTextColor(mColor);
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // Finger off the bounds
            if (!bounds.contains(x, y)) {
                _setTextColor(mColor);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onTouch to do the trick, one thing that is important here is to call `invalidate()` - tells the view to redraw itself with new data

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (bounds.contains(x, y)) {
                // Text pressed
                // Change paint, text size or what ever
                invalidate();
            }
        }
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              // Apply original paint, size, ..
              invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added my solution with moving finger.